# PrivateBytesLimit in web.config doesn't change cache EffectivePrivateBytesLimit

Tags: iis, cache, asp.net

Our web-server has a worker process (w3wp.exe) that uses too much memory. Following [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/348904/415490) I tried to limit how much memory the process can use for caching in the `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <!-- Limit cache memory -->
        <cache disableExpiration="false" disableMemoryCollection="false" percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit="25" privateBytesLimit="20971520" privateBytesPollTime="00:01:00" />
    </caching>
    <!-- rest of system.web ... -->
</system.web>
```

My tests show I am unable to change the `EffectivePrivateBytesLimit` property of the cache by doing this. Here is how I check the cache's memory limit:

```
' Get cache limit
new System.Web.Caching.Cache().EffectivePrivateBytesLimit
```

The `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemory` of the cache **does** change. Why isn't `EffectivePrivateBytesLimit` changing?

**Sources**

- [web.config cache element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228248(v=vs.100))
- [Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.effectiveprivatebyteslimit)
- [Explanation of EffectivePrivateBytesLimit calculation](https://forums.asp.net/t/1697393.aspx?Does%20VS%20have%20limit%20on%20HttpRuntime%20Cache%20size%20)

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Have you found any additional info about this?

Comment: @JNappi I have not found anything yet.